# update all record where id is not equal current id

Tags: codeigniter

```
$id = $this->db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS ID")->row();
$w = $this->db->query("UPDATE bet_type_default SET current = 0 WHERE id <> ".$id."  ");
```

Error output is:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
>
> Filename: models/model_name.php
>
> Line Number: 29 A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1
>
> UPDATE bet_type_default SET current = 0 WHERE id <>
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\testing\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
$row = $this->db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS ID ")->row_array();

$w = $this->db->query(
             "UPDATE bet_type_default SET current = 0 WHERE id <> ".$row['ID']
     );
```

Instead you should have used active record pattern :

```
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
$this->db->where('id <> ', $id)
         ->update('bet_type_default' , array('current'=>0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this-

```
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
$w = $this->db->query("UPDATE bet_type_default SET current = 0 WHERE id <> $id");
```